# Arrange page priority

Tags: android

I started to create an android application. At first, I planned it will be 5 pages and I wrote Xml and java codes for the first page and the others. Now I realized I made a mistake. The first page can not be a first page. Means; there should be a new page before the first page. I wrote codes for that new page but I can't see it when I run the project. What should I do? Thanks already.

Comment: Page?  Do you mean Activity?  You want your app to start with Activity A, not Activity B?

Comment: you must post your code. That's what you should do

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the activity to the AndroidManifest.xml

There you can specify which Activity should be the Launch-Activity by setting the intent-filter like:

```
        <activity android:name="LaunchActivity">
            <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Be sure **only** your Launchy Activity has that intent signature though.

No offense, but that's pretty basic knowledge, maybe you should read a few tutorials before jumping into development?